# Mac OS X firewall settings

Tags: macos, firewall, pf

I'm having some issues with setting up firewall on Mac OS X El Capitan version 10.11.4.

I have number of network interfaces including en3, which is my main ethernet connection and and gif0 which is tunnel to ipv6 tunnel broker.

I need to block all outgoing connections on en3 to some network, let it be for example `1.1.1.1/17`. It is pretty easy thing to do on linux, but on OSX I can't find a solution.

Comment: Could you possibly go into detail on the methods you have tried so we don't repeat things?